# Any way to download a Facebook group?

Tags: bash, facebook, download, command-line-interface

Sorry for a strange question. 
I'm an admin of a very useful Facebook group. There is a lot of valuable info, which I'd like to have offline. Is there any (cli) method to download it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use online services like [Sociograph](http://www.sociograph.io)and [Grytics](https://grytics.com/) to get data and even export them(I tried sociograph).

If you want to download the data yourself, then you need to build a program that gets the data for you through the graph api and from there you can do whatever you want with the data you get.

Here is a simple I hacked in python to get the data from a facebook group.
Using this [SDK](https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import facebook
from collections import Counter

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='fb_access_token', version='2.7', timeout=2.00)
posts  = []


post = graph.get_object(id='{group-id}/feed') #graph api endpoint...group-id/feed
group_data = (post['data'])

all_posts = []

"""
 Get all posts in the group.
"""
def get_posts(data=[]):
    for obj in data:
        if 'message' in obj:
            print(obj['message'])
            all_posts.append(obj['message'])


"""
return the total number of times each word appears in the posts
"""
def get_word_count(all_posts):
    all_posts = ''.join(all_posts)
    all_posts = all_posts.split()
    for  word in all_posts:
        print(Counter(word))

    print(Counter(all_posts).most_common(5)) #5 most common words



"""
return number of posts made in the group
"""
def posts_count(data):
    return len(data)
```

get_posts(group_data)
   get_word_count(all_posts)
Basically using the graph-api you can get all the info you need about the group such as likes on each post, who liked what, number of videos, photos etc and make your deductions from there.

I googled but couldn't find a bash script for this.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have used this, its only returning 25 posts. How I can increase the limit to get all posts from group? Do you need to be admin of the group to get data?

Answer (score 1):

On [the relevant list of repos on GitHub](https://github.com/topics/facebook-scraper), one that seems to be popular, up to date, and to work well is https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper

Example CLI usage:

```
pip install facebook-scraper
facebook-scraper --filename nintendo_page_posts.csv --pages 10 nintendo
```